# react-native-fcm event handler not firing (Firebase Cloud Messaging)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on `react-native-fcm` push notifications for Android. I have followed the `react-native-fcm` official website's instructions carefully
but when my application is in the foreground I am not getting push notification data into my console. Here is a code sample with the event handler I am using:

```
FCM.getInitialNotification().then(notification => {
    console.log(notification)
    alert(`init:`);
});
```

Comment: Which platform is this? Android/iOS or on both?

Comment: android platform

Comment: Did you create the [notification channel](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm/blob/master/Examples/simple-fcm-client/app/App.js#L39)? What android version are you testing with?